# Can I put ServiceWorker sync on hold using code?

Tags: html, synchronization, service-worker

OK, so we have an offline first application that makes calls to a back-end API.

We would like to use Service Worker's sync to cache calls to the API when the application is offline, and then process those calls when the browser's back online.

The complication is that we need to have a valid OWIN token when we are making the API call.

There is a solution [outlined here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/133333/best-practice-pattern-for-service-worker-background-sync-with-csrf-protection) that says we can just get a token when we need it; but this won't work for our application because we only allow one active session per user.
So if we get a token in code we risk kicking a real world user currently busy on the application.

So the question is this: - Can we get the Service-Worker sync to pause in code as outlined below?

1. We tell the service worker sync process to "stop for now" in our code when a user ends their session in the application.

At this point it is important that the sync process keeps track of all the calls that need to be processed, but to not process any of them. Also, any additional sync calls should just be "added to the queue".

2. When the next user gets a valid OWIN token, we could tell the sync process to "continue as usual".

So far my googling returns nothing that deals with this explicitly; but most of the documentation implies that this is not possible.

Does anyone know for sure if this is possible or not?

Comment: How long do these tokens live? "we only allow one active session per user" - does that mean it fails with multiple tabs? How do you avoid the same issue with overlapping fetches from a single page?

Comment: We store the token as a bearer cookie on the browser.
This means that the same token is valid across all pages and all tabs (as long as the user doesn't close the browser, or select the "logout" menu option).

Comment: Couldn't the same solution be used here? Put the token in IndexedDB and access it from the service worker.

Comment: Interesting idea. This would work intermittently - because the token may not be valid when the browser goes back online (in the case where the user goes online using a different device all their previous tokens get revoked, and the one stored in IndexedDB will no longer work).

Comment: If the token fails, request a new one?

Answer (score 1):

OK, So From the discussion above, and from other offline discussions;
The trivial answer to the question is "No" - as at 13 Jan 2017 (yes, it's Friday); you can't pause the service worker sync.

So as a work-around; there were two approaches that we could find

(both involve a re-think of the solution to some extent).

1. If possible get a new OWIN Authentication token from within your sync code.
2. If 1 is not possible, then split up your API calls into 3 categories.

2.1 Get calls; these can be processed through the service-worker's standard caching mechanisms.

2.2 Non-Get calls where the response can be ignored. These can be added to an IndexedDB table, and a web-worker can be kicked off to process them after the user connects to the database.

2.3 Non-Get calls where the response is required. These do not happen too often; so for each case write seperate code paths for online / offline situations.

That's about it; Option 2 works for my current project. There may be projects where option 2 is still not feasable.